# Transition between 2 recycler views having cards

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, transition

I have 2 recycler views that have cards.They basically look the same have the same number of cards and everthing. The first one is for like viewing and other stuff and the second one is only for deleting cards. OnlongClicking a card in the first recycler view triggers the opening of the second recycler view. I wanted to add transitions in between them like what keep notes has done when a card is long clicked. Both the recycler view use the same adapter. I have set what the adapter should do based on passing context to the adapter. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uh4hh.png) this is my 1st layout having the 1st recycler view.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qO6t5.png) this is the 2nd layout having the second recycler view.I want like a seamless transition for the tool bar again just like what Google keeps has done.A simple solution would be preferred as I am very new to this stuff.

Here is the java code for the adapter.

```
public class Task_recycle_view_adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Task_recycle_view_adapter.ViewHolder>{

private List<struct_task> task_list= new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> isSelected=new ArrayList<String>();
protected Context context1;
protected Context context2;
private String labelName;
private String taskName;
private ConstraintLayout label_menu_avatar;

public Task_recycle_view_adapter(Context context1,Context context2)
{
    this.context1=context1;
    this.context2=context2;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {//parent is the parent of the recycle view it is taken as an arg to use it to attach the every view to the parent view
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_task,parent,false);//to inflate a layout
    ViewHolder holder= new ViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.taskname.setText(task_list.get(position).getTask_name());
    holder.taskid.setText(String.valueOf(task_list.get(position).getTask_id()));

    if(context2==null && context1!=null) {
        String taskName=task_list.get(position).getTask_name();
        Long taskid=task_list.get(position).getTask_id();
        String duedate=task_list.get(position).getDue_date();
        holder.parent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context1);
                ArrayList<SubTaskModel> subtask_list=(ArrayList<SubTaskModel>) dataBaseHelper.getAllSubTasksFor(labelName, Long.parseLong(holder.taskid.getText().toString()));
                Intent intent1 =new Intent(context1,ViewTaskActivity.class);
                intent1.putExtra("label_name",labelName);
                intent1.putExtra("task_id",taskid);
                intent1.putExtra("task_name",taskName);
                intent1.putExtra("due_date",duedate);
                intent1.putParcelableArrayListExtra("subtask_list", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) subtask_list);
                context1.startActivity(intent1);
            }
        });

        holder.parent.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(context1, Delete_page_Activity.class);
                intent2.putParcelableArrayListExtra("task_list", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) task_list);
                intent2.putExtra("label_name",labelName);
                intent2.putExtra("selected_task",taskName);
                Pair[] pairs = new Pair[1];
                pairs[0]= new Pair<View,String>(label_menu_avatar,"transition1");
                ActivityOptions options= ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation((Activity) context1,pairs);
                context1.startActivity(intent2,options.toBundle());
                return true;
            }
        });

    }

    if(context2!=null && context1==null)
    {
        if(taskName.equals(task_list.get(position).getTask_name()))
        {
            holder.active=1;
            isSelected.add(holder.taskid.getText().toString());

            holder.parent.findViewById(R.id.layout_for_every_task).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_for_task_card);
        }
        holder.parent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(holder.active==0) {
                        isSelected.add(holder.taskid.getText().toString());
                        v.findViewById(R.id.layout_for_every_task).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_for_task_card);
                    holder.active=1;

                }
                else {
                        isSelected.remove(holder.taskid.getText().toString());
                        v.findViewById(R.id.layout_for_every_task).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_for_task_card_transparent);
                        holder.active=0;

                }
            }
        });
    }

    // subtasks 1 to 5
    if(task_list.get(position).getSubtask1()!=null)
        holder.subtask1.setText(task_list.get(position).getSubtask1());
    else
        holder.subtask1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    if(task_list.get(position).getSubtask2()!=null)
        holder.subtask2.setText(task_list.get(position).getSubtask2());
    else
        holder.subtask2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    if(task_list.get(position).getSubtask3()!=null)
        holder.subtask3.setText(task_list.get(position).getSubtask3());
    else
        holder.subtask3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    if(task_list.get(position).getSubtask4()!=null)
        holder.subtask4.setText(task_list.get(position).getSubtask4());
    else
        holder.subtask4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    if(task_list.get(position).getSubtask5()!=null)
        holder.subtask5.setText(task_list.get(position).getSubtask5());
    else
        holder.subtask5.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    // due date
    if(task_list.get(position).getDue_date()!=null)
        holder.duedate.setText(task_list.get(position).getDue_date());
    else
        holder.duedate.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    // progress
    holder.progresscircle.setProgress(task_list.get(position).getProgress());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return task_list.size();
}

public void setTask_list(List<struct_task> task_list) {
    this.task_list = task_list;//to refresh the data inside the recycler view

}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}

public String getLabelName() {
    return labelName;
}

public void setLabelName(String labelName) {
    this.labelName = labelName;
}

public ArrayList<String> getIsSelected() {
    return isSelected;
}

public String getTaskName() {
    return taskName;
}

public void setTaskName(String taskName) {
    this.taskName = taskName;
}

public void setLabel_menu_avatar(ConstraintLayout label_menu_avatar) {
    this.label_menu_avatar = label_menu_avatar;
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{// holds the view for every item inside the recycle view

    private TextView taskname,taskid,duedate,subtask1,subtask2,subtask3,subtask4,subtask5;
    private CardView parent;
    private ProgressBar progresscircle;

    public void setActive(int active) {
        this.active = active;
    }
    private int active;
    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        taskid=itemView.findViewById(R.id.task_id);
        taskname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.task_name);
        parent = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_for_every_task);
        duedate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.due_date);
        progresscircle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.progress_circular);
        subtask1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.subtask_1);
        subtask2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.subtask_2);
        subtask3 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.subtask_3);
        subtask4 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.subtask_4);
        subtask5 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.subtask_5);
        active=0;

    }
}
```

}

Here is the code for the 1st activity i.e the 1st image:

```
public class TaskPageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView task_rv;//task recycler view
private FloatingActionButton addTask;
private long tasksNum;
private String labelName;
private DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
private Task_recycle_view_adapter adapter= new Task_recycle_view_adapter(this,null);
private List<struct_task> tasks;
private EditText searchBar;
private ConstraintLayout search_btn;
private ConstraintLayout calendar_btn;

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_task_title);

    getWindow().getSharedElementExitTransition();

    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    search_btn= findViewById(R.id.search_btn);
    calendar_btn=findViewById(R.id.calendar_btn);
    search_btn.setClickable(true);
    search_btn.setFocusable(true);
    labelName = getIntent().getExtras().getString("832715");
    TextView txtLabelName = findViewById(R.id.Label_name);
    txtLabelName.setText(labelName);
    task_rv = findViewById(R.id.Recycle_view_task);
    addTask = findViewById(R.id.add_task);
    searchBar= (SearchBar) findViewById(R.id.search_bar);

    tasksNum = getTasksNum(labelName, dataBaseHelper, adapter); //displays all tasks and return number of tasks
    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params= (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) searchBar.getLayoutParams();

    addTask.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        tasksNum = getTasksNum(labelName, dataBaseHelper, adapter);
        Intent intent = new Intent(TaskPageActivity.this, AddTaskPageActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("labelName", labelName);
        intent.putExtra("taskID", tasksNum);
        startActivity(intent);
    });

    search_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(searchBar.getVisibility()==View.INVISIBLE) {
                search_btn.setAlpha(.5f);
                searchBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                searchBar.requestFocus();
                imm.showSoftInput(searchBar,InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
                ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params= (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) searchBar.getLayoutParams();
                params.verticalBias = .55f;
                searchBar.setLayoutParams(params);
                searchBar.requestFocus();
            }
            else {
                searchBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                search_btn.setAlpha(1.0f);
            }
        }
    });



    searchBar.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus) {
                ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) searchBar.getLayoutParams();
                if(params.verticalBias==.9f) {
                    searchBar.requestFocus();
                    params.verticalBias = .55f;
                    searchBar.setLayoutParams(params);
                }

                searchBar.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                        if((event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) && params.verticalBias==.55f)
                        {
                            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) searchBar.getLayoutParams();
                            searchBar.requestFocus();
                            params.verticalBias = .9f;
                            searchBar.setLayoutParams(params);
                            searchBar.clearFocus();
                            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(searchBar.getWindowToken(),0);

                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });


    searchBar.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            filter(s.toString());
        }
    });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(TaskPageActivity.this).create();
    calendar_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(calendar_btn.getAlpha()==1.0f) {
                calendar_btn.setAlpha(.5f);
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                View view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_calendar,null);
                alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                alertDialog.setView(view1);
                CalendarView mCalendarView= view1.findViewById(R.id.calendar);
                mCalendarView.setMinDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        }
    });

    alertDialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            if(calendar_btn.getAlpha()==.5f)
                calendar_btn.setAlpha(1.0f);
        }
    });


}

private void filter(String string) {
    ArrayList<struct_task> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(struct_task item: tasks)
    {
        if(item.getTask_name().contains(string) || item.getTask_name().contains(string.toUpperCase()))
        {
            filteredList.add(item);
        }
    }
    if(filteredList.size()!=0) {
        adapter.setTask_list(filteredList);
        task_rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(searchBar.getText().toString().length()!=0) {
        showAllTasks(labelName, dataBaseHelper, adapter);
        searchBar.setText(null);
        searchBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        search_btn.setAlpha(1.0f);

    }
    else if(searchBar.getText().toString().length()==0)
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) searchBar.getLayoutParams();
    showAllTasks(labelName, dataBaseHelper, adapter);
    if(params.verticalBias==.54f) {
        searchBar.requestFocus();
        params.verticalBias = .9f;
        searchBar.setLayoutParams(params);
        searchBar.clearFocus();
    }
    if(searchBar.getText().toString().length()==0) {
        showAllTasks(labelName, dataBaseHelper, adapter);
    }
    else {
        filter(searchBar.getText().toString());
    }
    super.onResume();
}

private void showAllTasks(String labelName, DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper, Task_recycle_view_adapter adapter) {
    tasks = dataBaseHelper.getAllTasksFor(labelName);
    adapter.setLabelName(labelName);
    adapter.setTask_list(tasks);
    task_rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    task_rv.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2,StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
}

long getTasksNum(String labelName, DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper, Task_recycle_view_adapter adapter) {
    return dataBaseHelper.getLastTaskID(labelName)+1; //to determine ID of next task
}

@Override
protected void onUserLeaveHint() {
    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) searchBar.getLayoutParams();
    params.verticalBias=.9f;
    searchBar.setLayoutParams(params);
    searchBar.setText(null);
    searchBar.clearFocus();
    super.onUserLeaveHint();
}
```

}

And finally for the 2nd activity which is triggered by longclicking any card

```
public class Delete_page_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Task_recycle_view_adapter recycle_view_adapter = new Task_recycle_view_adapter(null,this);
private ArrayList<String> delete_list=new ArrayList<>();
private DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
private String labelName=null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_delete_page);
    overridePendingTransition(0,0);


    Toolbar toolbar=findViewById(R.id.toolbar_bar);
    ImageView close_btn=findViewById(R.id.close_btn);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);

    ArrayList<struct_task> task_list = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("task_list");
    labelName=getIntent().getExtras().getString("label_name");
    String task = getIntent().getExtras().getString("selected_task");


    Log.e("test",labelName);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.delete_Recycler_View);

    recycle_view_adapter.setTaskName(task);
    recycle_view_adapter.setTask_list(task_list);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recycle_view_adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2,StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));

    close_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu,menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.tool_bar_item1:
            delete_list = recycle_view_adapter.getIsSelected();
            if(delete_list.size()==0)
            {
                Toast toast1= new Toast(this);
                toast1.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_toast_msg1,null);
                view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_for_calendar);
                toast1.setView(view);
                toast1.show();
            }
            else {
                for (int task = 0; task < delete_list.size(); task++) {

                    dataBaseHelper.deleteOneTask(labelName, Long.parseLong(delete_list.get(task)));
                }
                finish();
            }
            break;

        case R.id.tool_bar_item2:
            Boolean flag=dataBaseHelper.deleteAllCompletedTasks(labelName);
            if(flag)
                finish();
            else
            {
                Toast toast2= new Toast(this);
                toast2.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_toast_msg2,null);
                view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_for_calendar);
                toast2.setView(view);
                toast2.show();
            }
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

I have added the code related to the scene transititon which is in the adapter.

here is a gif of the problem when i add a scene transition

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2r72.gif)

As u can see there are 2 pauses when going from 1st to 2nd activity 1st pause being longer 2nd one shorter. And also a pause when exiting the 2nd activity which seems to have the same duration as the 2nd pause.

Comment: this is quite a broad question, not sure you'll find an answer for that here. regardless, you should probably add a language tag to your question

Comment: I tried using scene transitions and it gave the effect I was looking for  but the recycler view part was going black and for a like a sec and then my animation were animating.

Comment: that's a great place to start, you should add all your relevant code to your post, people are 100% willing to help you debug existing code and severely less willing to write complete features for you

Comment: Yea I understand will do that. As u can guess this is my first time on stack

Comment: In both the xml files for the activities I have used constraint layout is that the problem somehow.